# Multiple laravel-ckeditor on the same page throws error

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

In my HTML I have two textareas, one is for body and one is for the body and the other is for the excerpt both of them are assigned the id `article-ckeditor`. When I load the page in the browser, I can see only the body textarea has turned into a ckeditor but excerpt has not. And in my console I see the following error:

> The editor instance "article-ckeditor" is already attached to the
>   provided element.

How do I attach multiple ckeditor on the same page?

Comment: You have to have different ids for each element (i.e. body-editor & excerpt-editor) and assign CKEditor to each of them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
...
<textarea id="body-editor" name="body"></textarea>
<textarea id="excerpt-editor" name="excerpt"></textarea>
...
```

In your Javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("body-editor");
CKEDITOR.replace("excerpt-editor");
```